# How to install xps package for R 3.0.3

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am trying to install the **xps** package from http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/xps.html
for R 3.0.3 on Windows 8.1 x64.

When I try:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("xps")
```

I get the following messages:

```
BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org
Using Bioconductor version 2.13 (BiocInstaller 1.12.0), R version 3.0.3.
Installing package(s) 'xps'
package ‘xps’ is available as a source package but not as a binary
Warning message:
package ‘xps’ is not available (for R version 3.0.3)
```

So I try installing by downloading the package source for [xps](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/src/contrib/xps_1.22.2.tar.gz)
When I try to install it I get the following message:

```
* installing *source* package 'xps' ...
testing for presence of ROOT...
perl: not found
   found  of ROOT in directory C:\root\/bin...OK
** libs
  running 'src/Makefile.win' ...
Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
g++ -pipe -mwindows  -I/include -include w32pragma.h -O2 -DWIN32 -c TMLMath.cxx
cc1plus.exe: fatal error: w32pragma.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [TMLMath.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make --no-print-directory -f "Makefile.win"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'xps'
* removing 'D:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.3/library/xps'
```

Comment: Do you have http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ installed? The error regards not finding perl, but I don't see perl in the list of RTools utilities, so my first guess about the cause may be wrong. Windoze users do need to specify the 32/64 bit status of a lot of their setup. You haven't done any of that yet.

Answer (score 0):

The [xps landing page](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/xps.html) says that xps is not available for 64-bit windows. If you run 32-bit R you'll be able to install the binary with biocLite.